# Simple transfer in Python: 'not enough signers'

Tags: python, solana-py

and apologies if there's a obvious better place to ask this.

I'm writing experimental [Python 3.12](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3120b3/) code to move SOL from/to an address I create "by hand" and a centralized exchange ([Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/)), like this:

```
from solders.keypair import Keypair
import base58

# Create keys and a Solana address
by_hand_keypair = Keypair()
by_hand_sol_address = base58.b58encode(bytes(by_hand_keypair.pubkey())).decode("utf-8")
```

Now I then transferred 0.03 SOL to my new address via Kraken Pro and wait a bit...

```
# ... and check if it's there:
    
from solana.rpc.api import Client 
   
client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/")
print(f"New Solana address balance: {client.get_balance(by_hand_keypair.pubkey()).value}")
```

It is, showing the right balance (30000000)

Now I try to transfer some back

```
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solders.system_program import transfer
from solders.system_program import TransferParams
    
kraken_sol_address = "C2od3xYdTh4nbt9WP3mSN67rFhDZ3MGKood8LtyJGaui"
kraken_pub_key = Pubkey(base58.b58decode(kraken_sol_address))
    
blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash().value.blockhash
transaction = Transaction(fee_payer=by_hand_keypair.pubkey(), recent_blockhash=blockhash)
transaction.add(
    transfer(
        TransferParams(
            from_pubkey=by_hand_keypair.pubkey(),
            to_pubkey=kraken_pub_key,
            lamports=10000000
        )
    )
)
transaction.sign(by_hand_keypair)
response = client.send_transaction(transaction)
```

It's here I get the `SignerError: not enough signers`

What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

It's subtle, but `send_transaction` resigns the transaction with the provided signers, so you should be able to fix it by removing the call to `sign` and instead passing the signer to `send_transaction`:

```
response = client.send_transaction(transaction, by_hand_keypair)
```

Looking at the code at https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/36ab2b5343d3f45cbe562df86e2d04101e101e71/src/solana/rpc/api.py#L998 and a test using `send_transaction` at https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/36ab2b5343d3f45cbe562df86e2d04101e101e71/tests/integration/test_http_client.py#L89